# Create an array with depth from and order column in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have stored in a database a list of members with a order column.
On this table, I have some members with the same order number.
That means the rows with the same order are child  of "Folder" member.

I get something like this from members table:

```
membername, order
'Anna', 1 
'Michael', 2
'Melissa', 2
'Charlie', 3
```

The jQuery plugin I'm using (DasBaum) support next input example on a javascript array:

```
items: [
            {label:'Anna'},
            {
                label:'Folder',
                items: [{label:'Michael', label:'Melissa'}]
            },
            {label:'Charlie'},
        ]
```

I was thinking to make the array as a string with PHP but I really don't know how to handle the foreach for the childrens and the "Folders".

```
$output = "";

foreach ($dbdata->members as $member) {
    // $member->order 
    // $member->membername;
}

dd($output);
```

Comment: Have a try on your own first. This is not a `code my appfor me` site

Comment: of course this is not a `code my app for me site`, and I really don't want to copy and paste a comment. I need an idea about how to handle the children, because I must create the "folder" array before the foreach knows if the order is the same that the previous one.

Comment: Its not a `suggest a way for me to do` site either. Its for specific contained coding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do first is to group those values accordingly, then after grouping them, just use `json_encode()`. So really have to use `$.ajax` in this one. In this example, I just used jQuery. Since you really don't have enough code, I'll just make up some dummy data (you dont have the database queries necessary anyway). Consider this example: [**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CdlPcY)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['get_values'])) {
    // select  * from table (this is a sample, just a simulation)
    $values_from_db = array(
        array('membername' => 'Anna', 'order' => 1),
        array('membername' => 'Michael', 'order' => 2),
        array('membername' => 'Melissa', 'order' => 2),
        // array('membername' => 'Jack', 'order' => 2),
        array('membername' => 'Charlie', 'order' => 3),
    );

    $group = array();
    // grouping first
    foreach($values_from_db as $key => $value) {
        $group[$value['order']][] = $value['membername'];
    }

    $items = array();
    // format to items
    foreach($group as $key => $value) {
        if(count($value) > 1) {
            $sub_items = array();
            foreach($value as $val) {
                $sub_items[] = array('label' => $val);
            }
            $items[] = array('label' => 'Folder', 'items' => $sub_items);
        } else {
            $items[] = array('label' => $value[0]);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($items, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    exit;
}


?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mkleinhans.de/github/dasBaum/dasBaum.css" />
<div id="tree"></div>
<!-- <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.mkleinhans.de/github/dasBaum/examples/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mkleinhans.de/github/dasBaum/dasBaum.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: document.URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_values: true},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(items) {
            $('#tree').dasBaum({
                sort: false,
                foldersOnTop: false,
                items: items
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Only valid for 1 child depth)

First, We need to handle if we are going to have children.

Then, we create an array with a counter of number of childs for each order value.

And We set the counter of each one.

Now, we can make the main foreach and handle if the member have children or not.

If it's true We make the "folder" item and another foreach to fill the items array.

If it's false We fill the array without children.

Finally, We mark if this order was parsed before to avoid to make an array for each item for each order.

```
    $groups = [];

    foreach ($dbdata->members as $member){
        $groups[$member->order] = 0;
        $parsed[$member->order] = 0;
    }

    foreach ($dbdata->members as $member){
        $groups[$member->order]++;
    }

    $output = "[";
    foreach ($dbdata->members as $member) {
        if ($groups[$member->order] > 1 and $parsed[$member->order] == 0){
            $output .= "{
                label:'Folder',
                items: [";
            foreach ($dbdata->members as $child) {
                if ($child->order == $member->order){
                    $output .= "{label:'".$child->membername."'},";
                }
            }

            $output .= "]
                },";
        }elseif ($groups[$member->order] <= 1 and $parsed[$member->order] == 0){
            $output .= "{label:'".$member->membername."'},";
        }
        $parsed[$member->order] = 1;
        //$prueba .= "·" . $member->order . ") " . $member->membername;
    }
    $output .= "]";
```

Now We can use the `$output` variable in javascript code to call the plugin.